# Модальное окно semantic-ui-react из примера не открывается при нажатии

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

Попробовал использовать стандартное модальное окно semantic-ui-react, взятое из [примера](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#types-basic):

```html
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Header, Icon, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const ModalBasicExample = () => (
    <Modal trigger={<Button>Basic Modal</Button>} basic size='small'>
        <Header icon='archive' content='Archive Old Messages' />
        <Modal.Content>
            <p>
                Your inbox is getting full, would you like us to enable automatic archiving of old messages?
            </p>
        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
            <Button basic color='red' inverted>
                <Icon name='remove' /> No
            </Button>
            <Button color='green' inverted>
                <Icon name='checkmark' /> Yes
            </Button>
        </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
)

export default ModalBasicExample
```

добавил компонент в App:

```html
import React from 'react'
import BookTable from './BookTable'
import {AddBook} from './Add'
import './library.css'
import CommentsModal from './Comments';
import ModalBasicExample from "./Modal";

export default class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        books: [],
        isLoading: false,
        isShowComments: false,
        comments: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchBooks();
    }

    fetchBooks = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        fetch('/all')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(books => this.setState({isLoading: false, books: books}));
    };

    handleAddBook = (book) => {
        const newBooks = [book, ...this.state.books];
        this.setState({books: newBooks});
    };

    handleDeleteBook = (id) => {
        const isNotId = book => book.id !== id;
        const updatedBooks = this.state.books.filter(isNotId);
        this.setState({books: updatedBooks});
    };

    handleCommentView = (comments) => {
        this.setState({comments, isShowComments: true});
    };

    render() {
        const { books, isLoading, isShowComments, comments } = this.state;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id="tablediv">
                    <h1>Library</h1>
                    {
                        isLoading ?
                            <p>Загружаю...</p>
                            : null
                    }
                    {
                        Array.isArray(books) ?
                        <BookTable
                            books={books}
                            onDelete={this.handleDeleteBook}
                            onCommentView={this.handleCommentView}
                        />
                        : null
                    }
                </div>
                <AddBook onAdd={this.handleAddBook}/>
                <ModalBasicExample/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Появилась кнопка, но она не реагирует на нажатие - модальное окно не выводится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен за подсказки.

Comment: постарайтесь вставить код, а не картинки, так как это получается невоспроизводимая проблема

Comment: Добавил код вместо изображений

Answer (score 0):

Проблема лечится добавлением пакета semantic-ui-css и его импортом:

import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

ответ перенесен из [англоязычной версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730958/modal-window-semantic-ui-react-from-example-not-opening/54731132#54731132).